# How to flush db query cache in yii2?

Tags: yii2, query-cache

How to handle it when some changes happen in specific table records ?

```
public static function getAirportWithCache($iata_code){

              $result = Airports::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($iata_code){
                     $res = Airports::find()
                               ->where(['iata_code' => $iata_code])
                               ->limit(1)
                               ->asArray()
                               ->one();
                     return $res;
              });
              return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Use [Delete()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#delete%28%29-detail).

Comment: In db query i don't have specific key. Like Yii::$app->cache->delete($key); In my example how to do it?

Comment: set specific key for cache then call delete(). Use [set()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-cache.html#set%28%29-detail)

Comment: Try: `Yii::$app->cache->set('dbCache', $result, 0, null)`

Comment: No. it is not working. As suggested by  @SohelAhmedM it will work but it will remove all cache data.

Comment: Not getting any error.

Comment: otherwise, you have to flush all cache.

Comment: Yes. i think this will be final solution.

Comment: nope,  may be still there is also some workaround for this, you should stay posted.

Comment: Okay. i have also raised this issue on  [yii2 forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69608-how-flush-db-query-cache)

Comment: You should simply use cache dependency : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies

Comment: @soju  i don't have key my scenario.

Comment: You don't need key, just dependency...

Answer (score 14):

For global cache, can use :

```
Yii::$app->cache->flush();
```

for spesific you can use TagDependency :

```
 //way to use
return Yii::$app->db->cache(function(){
    $query =  new Query();
    return $query->all();
}, 0, new TagDependency(['tags'=>'cache_table_1']));

//way to flush when modify table
TagDependency::invalidate(Yii::$app->cache, 'cache_table_1');
```

see the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-tagdependency.html

Comment: Thanks for the TagDependency example, it helped.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply use [`\yii\caching\DbDependency`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies), e.g. :

```
public static function getAirportWithCache($iata_code){
    // for example if airports count change, this will update your cache
    $dependency = new \yii\caching\DbDependency(['sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . Airports::tableName()]);
    $result = Airports::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($iata_code){
        return Airports::find()
            ->where(['iata_code' => $iata_code])
            ->limit(1)
            ->asArray()
            ->one();
    }, 0, $dependency);
    return $result;
}
```

[Read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies)...

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer as it is the correct solution according to yii2-specs!

Comment: I thought of doing this but how does Yii know when the data has changed? To know wouldn't it have to do a query to find out and hence defeat the purpose of caching in the first place!?

Answer (score 2):

Just execute `Yii::$app->cache->flush();` anywhere (probably in your controller)

PS: It will delete entire cache stored in your server

Comment: I will check. and how to handle if any changes happen in table specific record?

Comment: Also this will remove my whole caching. i want to specific for db queries.

Comment: This definitely is not the solution, as it will flush your whole cache. This means query-cache, rbac-cache, schema-cache about everything except if you had multiple cache-components attached...